# Get and post request from a website to a web service

Tags: spring-boot, rest, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have a website that needs to import data from my secured spring boot web service.
Is it possible to make call GET and POST requests to my webservice from the website without asking me for authenticating?
Is it possible to work with Jwt token when sending my requests?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What have you tried?  What's not working?  Where is the website and the service?  Are you aware of CORS?

Comment: What is your website? Is it a single-page application or anything else?

Comment: my website is a restaurant site composed of a single page from which we can order dishes

Comment: The creation and the management of the orders is done on my webservice. This is why I want the siteweb to connect to my webservice.

Comment: The product images are imported also from my webservice

Comment: my webservice is secured with spring security so we need to authenticate. The issue is that I want to send the request directely with jwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the JWT token in the request header and call GET/POST API.

Header Name is **Authorization** and value will be **Bearer <JWT_TOKEN>**

Like this

[image]